# Cannot convert column to JSON in Postgresql (Token "top" is invalid)

Tags: json, postgresql, alter-table

I would like to change one of my columns from `VARCHAR` to `JSON` in a Postgresql 9.4.4 database. The column contains text and also `null` values.

However, i get the error `Token "top" is invalid.`, which I don't understand at all.

```
ALTER TABLE schema1.table1
  ALTER COLUMN col5 TYPE JSON USING (col5::JSON);

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
   Detail: Token "top" is invalid.
   Where: JSON data, line 1: top...
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are all the non-null text contents in the column valid JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column `col5` contains values which are not valid json. You can check this with the function:

```
create or replace function valid_json(str varchar)
returns boolean language plpgsql as $$
declare
    j json;
begin
    j:= str;
    return true;
exception
    when others then return false;
end $$;

select *
from schema1.table1
where not valid_json(col5);
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you so much! The function is extremely helpful!